# AJAX in MVC does not call junction

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

index.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSuccessComment(data) {
        alert(data.resultMessage);
    }
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
{
    Url = Url.Action("AddCommentAjax"),
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccessComment",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}))
{
    @Html.TextArea("comment")
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить комментарий" />
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
namespace WebApplication12.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static List<string> _comments = new List<string>();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_comments);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddComment(string comment)
        {
            //необходимые действия
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCommentAjax(string comment)
        {
            //необходимые действия
            return Json(new { resultMessage = "Ваш комментарий добавлен успешно!" });
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that function `AddCommentAjax` does not get called on button click. How to fix that? What is the problem?

Comment: try onBegin method and check whether its working or not I think Ajax method is also incorrect

Answer (score 1):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddCommentAjax", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccessComment",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}))
```

Try something like this

Don't forget to include javascript file:

`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>`

Comment: It's call function, but reload whole page and I get JSON in response. But I doesn't need page reload, I need to call server function and as callback run client-side  function OnSuccessComment.

Comment: @NikitaPavlov check the update ans are you incuding the correct javascript file ie <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>